# Which scripture or book is the origin of the Surya Namaskara asanas?

Tags: yoga, asana

In which scripture (not of Kaliyuga), [Surya Namaskara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surya_Namaskara) (12 steps asana) is mentioned? I have checked Hatha yoga Pradipika and Yoga Sutras of Patanjali, but nowhere Surya Namaskara is mentioned.

I have found a related question [What is the origin of twelve Surya namaskar mantra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13904/5212) which asks for the origin of *the mantras* chanted during the asana but it doesn't ask about the origin of the asanas. I also doubt the so called surya namaskar mantras. They are just Surya mantras, nowhere it is mentioned that it is related to Suryanamaskar-12 Yoga Poses. Moreover Sun or Surya God have 1000 names or name mantras.

Comment: @Just_Do_It please note that it is not a Scripture but a book witten in kaliyug.

Comment: @Just_Do_It the book written in kaliyug contains mantras about Surya namaskar and not the Surya namaskar asanas

Comment: @Just_Do_It According to my opinion Surya namaskar is invented by kaliyug people. But I am not 100% sure, so asked this question.

Comment: Which scripture according to u was written in Kaliyuga that has these asanas? @Ram

Comment: @Rickross I don't know. The thing is I have not found this in ancient books. So it looked like it is Kaliyug invention.

Comment: @Rickross I do agree it is good and all. Power Yoga is also good. But made in Kaliyug.

Comment: Well Kaliyug can be more ancient than a Satya Yuga if that Satya Yuga is of the present Kalpa and the Kali Yuag is from a previous Kalpa. :D @Ram

Comment: @Rickross Well, I can't prove anything. But I can say Surya Namaskar is not mentioned in any ancient books which I am aware of. Maybe someone who has read more books on Yoga can help here.

Comment: @Ram If the mantras mention the Surya namaskar mantras, then that is the origin of the asanas also right?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma no it is not. Please read each and every word of the question about suryanamaskar mantras and read the book they have mentioned. It is only about mantras and not suryanamaskar 12 yoga poses.

Comment: @Ram Let's stop series of comments here. It is not closed because we can't answer or due to false opinions and don't vent your frustration on the users. It is not indecent behaviour or anything. This is only  marked as a duplicate question which can be reopened. I edited and voted to reopened the question. Wait for some time. If it's not reopened, flag for mod attention. If it is not done yet, raise this on [meta]. You can also join me on [chat] to discuss further but comments are not for discussion.

Comment: I have cast my reopen vote. IMO it's not a duplicate. Because you're asking for the origin of the postures whereas the other one is asking for the same of the Mantras. So, mite be quite closely related but not exactly dupe IMO. @Ram If you can cast reopen votes then pls do it.

Comment: @UdayKrishna haha yes if it can happen.

Comment: @UdayKrishna could you please be clear what you want to say?

Comment: @UdayKrishna oh ok nice to know.

Comment: I am also looking for the origin of  Surya Namaskara. Answers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Vineet I think answers will never be available as it looks like Surya namaskar is just of series of asanas complementing each other and invented by highly qualified yoga teacher in this Kaliyuga. But still let's see if any answer is available.

Comment: I have found scriptural references of only breath control from the Rigveda itself. Looking out in general, if it runs into me!